# apache redmine getting directory listing on /redmine

Tags: apache-2.2, redmine

I updated ruby on my ubuntu box and since then redmine is down.  My apache2.conf is as below

```
Include /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-5.0.23/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
     PassengerDefaultUser www-data
     PassengerRoot /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-5.0.23
     PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby
</IfModule>
```

sites-available/default is as below.

```
# redmine ###
    <Directory /var/www/redmine>
        RailsBaseURI /redmine
        PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
    </Directory>
```

When I goto url/redmine I get a directory listing and redmine doesn't get started. Any pointers?

Comment: Anything in Apache error log? Is the updated passenger module getting loaded correctly? Have you checked the passenger module path and passenger root if they are correct?

Comment: I got was getting the error "[warn] module passenger_module is already loaded, skipping"  ..... So I ran install-passenger-apache2-module. Also, dispatch.fcgi had /usr/bin/ruby1.8 changed that to /usr/bin/ruby. Apache2 error.log shows Passenger started " 2015-12-31 14:10:56.3151 1146/b777da50 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:504 ]: Starting Passenger UstRouter..."

Comment: Can you check the output of this pls: `sudo passenger-config validate-install`

Comment: Everything looks good. :-)

Comment: Looks like a rails problem.

Answer (score 0):

Run 'passenger start' from your root Redmine directory. That'll tell you if Passenger is working correctly.

If that's working correctly, post the contents of your .htaccess file.